# Music stuttering

Tags: memory

I'm trying to listen to music on my Mac, but no matter if it's via YouTube, Spotify or iTunes the music will simply stutter. My system specs are:

- macOS Mojave 10.14.3
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
- 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5
- 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3
- 86Gi of HD available (SSD)

I've tried disabling possible culprits, like intelisense scanning in VSCode or killing Docker, but the issue still remains (and I can't see anywhere them affecting the system in terms of memory usage).

[image]

On the memory tab I can't see anything spiking.

I'm a new Mac user, so apologies if I didn't include something obvious

Comment: What model of Mac? Mechanical hard drive or SSD? Chrome has traditionally been a resource hog. I'd certainly try quitting as many other user processes as possible and see if that improves things.

Comment: @benwiggy I've added these to my question (MacBook Pro, 2018 / SSD respectively). I'd agree with you If I saw spikes coming from Chrome, but there's nothing.

Comment: Is this music all streamed from the internet, or is it also music stored locally?

Comment: With Chrome not running the issue still occurs. The music is streamed from the internet, but connection is reliable.